# glusterFS with data lake

Tags: glusterfs, data-lakehouse

The project's core objective is to enhance data storage and analysis capabilities by integrating GlusterFS into a data lake infrastructure. This integration encompasses configuring a robust GlusterFS cluster, designing a user-friendly web application tailored for efficient file management, and establishing seamless connectivity between GlusterFS and the data lake environment. Leveraging GlusterFS's inherent scalability and fault tolerance, complemented by the simplicity of Docker containers for deployment, the project endeavors to optimize data handling and processing workflows across the infrastructure.

Through meticulous configuration and integration efforts, the project aims to create a cohesive environment where data can be stored, managed, and analyzed with ease. By incorporating GlusterFS into the data lake infrastructure, the project seeks to ensure streamlined data operations, ultimately fostering enhanced efficiency and effectiveness in managing vast volumes of data.